# Vue + typescript: how to annotate computed with types?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have the following vue code:

```js
const chosenWallet = computed({
      get() {
        return return wallet.value ? wallet.value!.name : null;
      },
      set(newVal: WalletName) {}
}
```

Which is throwing the following error:

```sh
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(getter: ComputedGetter<unknown>, debugOptions?: DebuggerOptions | undefined): ComputedRef<unknown>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ get(): WalletName | null; set(newVal: WalletName): void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComputedGetter<unknown>'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'get' does not exist in type 'ComputedGetter<unknown>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(options: WritableComputedOptions<WalletName>, debugOptions?: DebuggerOptions | undefined): WritableComputedRef<WalletName>', gave the following error.
    Type '() => WalletName | null' is not assignable to type 'ComputedGetter<WalletName>'.
      Type 'WalletName | null' is not assignable to type 'WalletName'.
        Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'WalletName'.
    44 |     const { wallet, setWallet } = useWallet();
    45 |     const chosenWallet = computed({
  > 46 |       get() {
       |       ^^^
    47 |         return wallet.value ? wallet.value!.name : null;
    48 |       },
    49 |       set(newVal: WalletName) {
```

I don't fully get it, but my hunch is that Vue's `computed()` value think the return value should only be `WalletName`, but of course the getter returns `WalletName | null`.

I tried putting types all over the place but the error won't go away. How do I fix it?

Comment: Can you add ``WalletName`` to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `computed`'s getter has its type inferred from the setter's argument, which is `WalletName`. The getter's return type is expected to match, but the conditional return makes the type `WalletName | null` (differs from the setter's argument), leading to the error you observed.

#### Solution

Either make the setter's argument `WalletName | null`:

```js
const chosenWallet = computed({
  get() {
    return wallet.value ? wallet.value.name : null
  },                        
  set(newVal: WalletName | null) {}
})
```

Or make the getter's return value match the setter's argument type:

```js
const chosenWallet = computed({
  get() {                                                 
    return (wallet.value ? wallet.value.name : null) as WalletName
  },
  set(newVal: WalletName) {}
})
```

Comment: omg of course! I tried adding everywhere but the setter, but you are 100% correct. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```js
const chosenWallet: WalletName | null  = computed({
      get(): WalletName | null {
        return return wallet.value ? wallet.value!.name : null;
      },
      set(newVal: WalletName) {}
}
```